# Creating a Graph With Specified Parameters Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a program function that allows a user to enter in specific dates , and the program will return a line graph with the specific range of dates that the user requires. My two columns are 'timestamp' and 'users_holding'. The code I currently have to plot the graph allows the user to say yes to wanting a graph, then it provides them with a line graph of the entire dataframe.

```
if graph == "Yes":
    data = DataFrame(df, columns=['timestamp', 'users_holding'])
    df.plot(x='timestamp', y='users_holding', kind='line')
    plt.show()
```

How would I modify my code so that the two dates inputted by the user are established as start and end points on the graph?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated

1. best practice is to ensure column is correct data type
2. a standard pandas column filter

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":["2020-07-01", "2020-07-10", "2020-07-20", "2020-07-30"], "user_holding":[15,20,30,45]})
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
start_date = "2020-07-10"
end_date = "2020-07-20"
df[df["timestamp"].between(start_date, end_date)].plot(x="timestamp", y="user_holding", kind="line")
df[df["timestamp"].isin([start_date, end_date])].plot(x="timestamp", y="user_holding", kind="line")
```

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1194217d0>
[image]

Comment: I'm using variables to allow the user to input a date. The input is then used to search for the corresponding date in a .csv file. How would I create a dataframe using those variables that I could then graph? ```#searching for start date
start_date_match = df[df['timestamp'].str.contains(start_date)]
maxvalues_start_date_match = start_date_match.max()

#searching for end date
end_date_match = df[df['timestamp'].str.contains(end_date)]
maxvalues_end_date_match = end_date_match.max()```